# Problem in setting up videoview in fragment. I shows Can't play the video

Tags: android, kotlin, android-videoview

Problem in setting up videoview in fragment. When I have set up the code in OnViewCreated() in my fragment but when video plays its shows message . Can't play the video. I have also given the internet permissions

My Fragment :

```
package com.service.bookitapp

import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.MediaController
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleCoroutineScope
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_home.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay


private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
private const val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"


class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private var param1: String? = null
    private var param2: String? = null
    private lateinit var viewpager : ViewPager2

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        return view
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val arrCategory = ArrayList<CategoryModel>()

        val recyclerView =view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerCategory)

        arrCategory.add(CategoryModel(R.drawable.electrician,"Electrician"))
        arrCategory.add(CategoryModel(R.drawable.plumber,"Plumber"))
        arrCategory.add(CategoryModel(R.drawable.acservice,"AC Service"))
        arrCategory.add(CategoryModel(R.drawable.carpentry,"Carpentry"))
        arrCategory.add(CategoryModel(R.drawable.drop,"Pick up & Drop"))
        arrCategory.add(CategoryModel(R.drawable.painting,"Paint Service"))
        arrCategory.add(CategoryModel(R.drawable.waterfilter,"Water Filter"))
        arrCategory.add(CategoryModel(R.drawable.packer,"Pack and Move"))

        recyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context,4)
        val recyclerAdapter = context?.let { RecycleCategoryAdapter(it,arrCategory) }
        recyclerView.adapter = recyclerAdapter



        viewpager = view.findViewById(R.id.imageSlider)
        val imageList = listOf(R.drawable.slider1,R.drawable.slider2,R.drawable.slider3)
        val adapter = context?.let { ViewerPagerAdapter(it,imageList) }
        viewpager.adapter = adapter
        viewpager.autoScroll(lifecycleScope,3000)


        // Video
        val mediaController = MediaController(context)
        val path : Uri = Uri.parse("http://videocdn.bodybuilding.com/video/mp4/62000/62792m.mp4")
        videoview.setMediaController(mediaController)
        videoview.setVideoURI(path)
        videoview.requestFocus()
        videoview.start()

    }

}
fun ViewPager2.autoScroll(lifecycleScope: LifecycleCoroutineScope, interval: Long){
lifecycleScope.launchWhenResumed{
    scrollIndefinitely(interval)
}
}
private suspend fun ViewPager2.scrollIndefinitely(interval: Long){
    delay(interval)
    val numberOfItems =adapter?.itemCount?:0
    val lastIndex = if(numberOfItems>0) numberOfItems - 1 else 0
    val nextItem = if(currentItem==lastIndex) 0 else currentItem + 1

    setCurrentItem(nextItem,true)
    scrollIndefinitely(interval)

}
```

The following file is my fragment xml file
fragment.home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FAF9F6"
    android:padding="6dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".HomeFragment">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/welcome_user"
            android:textColor="@color/teal_200"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:ignore="RelativeOverlap" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:src="@drawable/profile"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

    </RelativeLayout>



    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/catg"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textSize="22sp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerCategory">


    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/offers"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="22sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mainHeaderSlider">

        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/imageSlider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

This below is my MainActivity
HomePageActivity

```
package com.service.bookitapp

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_home_page.*



class HomePageActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page)

        val homeFragment = HomeFragment()
        val supportFragment = SupportFragment()
        val bookingsFragment = MyBookingsFragment()

        replaceFragment(homeFragment)
        botNavView.setOnItemSelectedListener(){
            when(it.itemId){
                R.id.navhome -> {
                    replaceFragment(homeFragment)
                    true
                }
                R.id.navbook -> {
                    replaceFragment(bookingsFragment)
                    true
                }
                R.id.navSupport -> {
                    replaceFragment(supportFragment)
                    true
                }
                else -> {
                    false
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment){
        val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        transaction.replace(R.id.container,fragment)
        transaction.commit()
    }


}
```